# Is there a syntax error in the script in installing conan/pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, conan

I am trying to follow on my Ubuntu 20.04.1

```
https://linuxhint.com/install_python_pip_tool_ubuntu/
```

At the step

`sudo python2 get-pip.py`

I receive the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24244, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmpKGsQqS/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
```

Is it the dust of the script or I do something wrong?

Comment: `f"ERROR: {exc}"` is Python 3 syntax (f-strings), so it you'd need to run this with a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: You can just do `apt install python3-pip` as well to get pip. I've found that to be pretty easy.

Comment: More specifically you need Python 3.6+.

Comment: forget `Python 2` and use only `Python 3`. And I think `Ubuntu 20.04.1` should already have installed `Python 3` and `pip` for `Python 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I do not use Python otherwise. I just wanted to install pip to install conan, to install my development environment. And, I had to rely on LinuxHint. Which suggests to install Python 2, then Python 3. BTW: my Ubuntu said: pip

Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones. After sudo apt install python3-pip ditto.

Comment: In the light of the comments found on the links shown in the closing comment, especially that "pip 21.0 dropped support for Python 2 and 3.5. The later versions require Python 3.6+. The syntax f"" is supported by Python 3.6+." I decided to drop conan, pip and Python from my toolchain. Thanks for the hints.